# How can I add custom name and Id to a time_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've a `time_select` and I want to add a custom name and id to the inputs, i tried with:

```rails
<td>
   <%= f_messenger.time_select :schedules,
       :id => "messenger_schedules_#{day}_end",
       :name => "messenger[schedules][#{day}][end]"
   %>
</td>
```

if I tried this with text inputs it works but on `time_select` I get something like:

`<select id="messenger_schedules_4i" name="messenger[schedules(4i)]">`

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

From [documents](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/time_select)

You can try this code following as:

```
<td>
   <%= f_messenger.time_select :schedules, '', prompt: {}, 
     id: "messenger_schedules_#{day}_end",
     name: "messenger[schedules][#{day}][end]"
   %>
</td>
```